# RedirectMatch rule works in testing, but not on live site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have implemented this rule:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/index.php/product/(.*) /product/$1`

The aim is to change the top URL to the bottom one:
`http://example.com/product/index.php/product/fresh-water
http://example.com/product/fresh-water`

On [a htaccess tester website](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) the rule works, however on the live testing site it redirects to

`http://example.com/`

Is there an error in my redirect rule, or is the issue elsewhere?

Full htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirects erroneous races pages to correct URLs
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/index.php/product/(.*) /product/$1
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/product/(.*) /product/$1
# END 301 redirects
```

Comment: Sure, will add it to my question.

Comment: Test it from a new browser. If that doesn't work then Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: Same issue in a new browser. In dev tools I disabled caching, checked 'preserve log' and then looked at the 'other' section on the 'network' tab, and there are two URL entries - both are this: /product/index.php/product/fresh-water

Comment: Check if there's one `AllowOverride All` on the Apache2 server config file